# How to get Soundcloud mp3 download URLs from shell?

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

There are a series of mp3s on Soundcloud that are uploaded by the author and for which he provides `.cue` files.

Here is an example of a Soundcloud page with accompanying download button: 
https://soundcloud.com/oriuplift/uponly-162

And of course you traditionally must click the download button:
[image: download button]

After inspecting the contents of the page (via `wget -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off https://soundcloud.com/oriuplift/uponly-162` and `grep`ing through it), I'm not seeing anything that gives this download URL or even the components to compose it.

How can one get the download URL (or the URL's constituent parts) from the Soundcloud page for further processing?

I'd be fine doing this from Ruby or Bash/ZSH.

Comment: Why don't you just click it from your browser and see what the download URL is?

Comment: The goal is to automate the process so that I can quickly download episodes of the podcasts vs going through a long manual process.

Comment: Ok, is there not a pattern to the download URL, based on the URL that you have?

Comment: @miken32 that's correct. That is exactly what I'm saying above.  There is no clear path to a download URL.  It seems that it's nowhere to be found in any of the JS or src files either.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [Python-based tool](https://github.com/flyingrub/scdl) that allows you to do this. You'll need to get an API token attached to your account. Assuming the file has one URL per line:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r url; do
    scdl -l "$url"
done < foo.cue
```